# Not Resolving dart dependencies

Tags: angular-dart, dart

I am trying to build a dart maven application and When I execute `maven clean install` it only showing `Resolving dependencies...` and doesn't happen anything. I am using the dart 1.12.1 version.

**EDIT:**

When I run `pub get` commend result is the same as previous it only showing `Resolving dependencies`.

Comment: I don't understand how your question regards dart, since given that maven is a tool for java dependencies. Also dart 1.12.1 is a bit ancient.

Comment: first I want to say, it is a legacy project not created in myself. when I execute `maven clean install` it run `pub get` commend using maven plugin. Please forgot maven things. when I execute `pub get` it doesn't download dart dependancies it only showing  `Resolving dependencies`.